# How to explain my standard error of my ANN prediction

Tags: machine-learning, standard-error

I have a question on how to satisfactorily explain the standard error of my ANN model.

For background, I have an ANN model that predicts protein post translational modifications based on their GC-MS data. I got pretty good results but the standard error of the model, not the prediction, is quite high. What I mean by this is that the error bars of the prediction shown in the figure below is due to plotting the model's average performance across multiple runs.

How do I explain this to a reviewer of our manuscript? He still interprets the error bars stemming from the prediction, not the model's average performance.

Here is the figure:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please clarify what you mean? For instance, are you following other work you can cite?